# Android code to read from /res/values-ar needed

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project on eclipse.
 By default the project  reads values from /res/values folder.
I have created another folder it's name values-ar.

How can I  make  the app reads from values-ar folder  .

I need I code please.

Comment: values-ar is for arabic locale. Do you want to use that

Answer (score 1):

You can set the locale that your application uses, so that it is different to the system settings.

Have a look at the Android developer page here for [`Configuration.locale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale).

Here is some code that does what you need:

```
/**
 * Sets the application to use a given language. This can be used for
 * implementing custom languages settings that are different to the system
 * settings.
 * 
 * @param appLanguage
 *            Language to use for this app. e.g. en
 */
private void setAppLocale(String appLanguage)
{
    // update language
    Locale customLocale = new Locale(appLanguage);
    Locale.setDefault(customLocale);

    // force app to update
    Configuration newConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
    newConfig.locale = customLocale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get the values from that folder via code. At run-time, Android will fetch values from that folder based on the device's locale. In your case, "ar" refers to Arabic, so set your device's locale and language to Arabic and Android will use the values in that folder when you run the app.

Comment: I want my application to be for arabic and english users  by    pressing a button to transfering to another language as user desires

Comment: In that case, this is what you are looking for -http://snowpard-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html

Answer (score -1):

Rename your values-ar to values delete the existing values folder copy the new values folder

Comment: I want my app to be for both arabic and english users